# How to get a single element array from a multiple element array of object?

Tags: javascript

This is my array :

```
mapping = [{sl_no : 1, type : "A", parent : ""},{sl_no : 2, type : "B", parent : "A"},{sl_no : 3, type : "D", parent : "B"}]
```

I want the array in the bellow format :

```
mapped_sl_no = [{sl_no : 1},{sl_no : 2},{sl_no : 3}]
```

Comment: Exact what you want goes here ->>>>var mapped = mapping.map(function(item) { return {sl_no:item.sl_no}; });

Answer (score 0):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is your friend...

```
   var mapped = mapping.map(function(item) { return item.sl_no; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a temporary object inside.

```js
var mapping = [{ sl_no: 1, type: "A", parent: "" }, { sl_no: 2, type: "B", parent: "A" }, { sl_no: 3, type: "D", parent: "B" }],
    mapped_sl_no = getMapped(mapping, 'sl_no');

function getMapped(array, k) {
    return array.map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        o[k] = a[k];
        return o;
    });
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(mapped_sl_no, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you all for your solutions.

Comment: @HassanAhamed, please vote and accept the answer you helped most.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `map` function:

```
var mapping = [{sl_no : 1, type : "A", parent : ""},{sl_no : 2, type : "B", parent : "A"},{sl_no : 3, type : "D", parent : "B"}];

var arr = mapping.map(function(obj){
  return {'sl_no': obj.sl_no};

})

console.log(arr); // the output is: [{sl_no : 1},{sl_no : 2},{sl_no : 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mapped_sl_no = [];

mapping.forEach(function(mapVal){
    mapped_sl_no.push({sl_no:mapVal.sl_no});
});
```

This should do it for you.

Else you can use libraries like underscore(http://underscorejs.org/) or lowdash(https://lodash.com/)